# How to change mouse pointer in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, 22.04, mouse-pointer

Due to screen size and screen resolution, I can hardly see the default mouse cursor on my laptop, therefore I have used the tweak tool to change the mouse cursor scheme to red glass. This works nicely, but gnome-terminal is not affected by this setting and keeps a very thin, hardly visible mouse pointer. I have already searched quite a lot, but could not find any means to configure a better visible mouse-pointer on the gnome-terminal. I would very much appreciate any explanation (why gnome-terminal does not respect the global cursor scheme) and suggestions on how to convince gnome-terminal to use a different mouse cusor.

Comment: As per the discussion at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7900, removing the offending `breeze-cursor-theme` package, or perhaps another mouse pointer theme package, might fix the issue for you. Another possibility is perhaps to revert the mentioned vte (Ubuntu source package: vte2.91) commit. (Unfortunately I don't understand what is exactly going on, so I cannot provide further explanation than what's already provided in that issue.)

Comment: This did the trick. I think this should be the official answer. If you would post it below I would accept it. If not thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately the kdenlive video editing package depends on breeze-cursor-theme, so removing it means losing kdenlive.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change the curser (mouse pointer) size in gnome , settings, under "universal access"

Comment: Thanks, this helped indeed, but I prefer the solution to uninstall the breeze-cursor-theme, which gives me a consistent mouse cursor everywhere.